# Error when testing secured spring repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I'm having problem with a Unit Test for a spring JPA repository.

I added another method to the repository which should return only entities for the logged in user:

```
@Query("select budget from Budget budget where budget.user.login = ?#{principal.username}")
List<Budget> findByUserIsCurrentUser();
```

Budget Resource:

```
 /**
 * GET  /budgets : get all the budgets.
 *
 * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and the list of budgets in body
 */
@GetMapping("/budgets")
@Timed
public List<Budget> getAllBudgets() {
    log.debug("REST request to get all Budgets");
    return budgetRepository.findByUserIsCurrentUser();
}
```

I adjusted the test for the getAllBudgets and added the .with(user) part:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void getAllBudgets() throws Exception {

  budgetRepository.saveAndFlush(budget);

  // Create security-aware mockMvc
  restBudgetMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
      .webAppContextSetup(context)
      .apply(springSecurity())
      .build();
  budgetRepository.saveAndFlush(budget);
  // Get all the points
  restBudgetMockMvc.perform(get("/api/budgets?sort=id,desc")
          .with(user("user").roles("user")))
          .andExpect(status().isOk())
          .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
          .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].id").value(hasItem(budget.getId().intValue())))
          .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].name").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_NAME.toString())));

}
```

But now the test Fails with https://pastebin.com/8aLDTauC:

```
<testcase name="getAllBudgets" classname="com.pahofmann.budget.web.rest.BudgetResourceIntTest" time="0.19">
<failure message="java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.[*].id" Expected: a collection containing <7> but: " type="java.lang.AssertionError">
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.[*].id" Expected: a collection containing <7> but: at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20) at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:74) at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers$1.match(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:87) at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171) at com.pahofmann.budget.web.rest.BudgetResourceIntTest.getAllBudgets(BudgetResourceIntTest.java:177) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75) at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86) at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252) at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35) at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32) at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35) at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146) at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128) at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</failure>
```

It seems that there is no value in the array, but it is working fine without the user part. The application itself is working fine, what do I need to change to get the test working with the User?

Comment: I added a pastebin link. The Stacktrace should be better readable that way.

Comment: You should post the method of the REST controller

Comment: I added the BudgetResource, the code can also be found here: https://github.com/pahofmann/budget/ I can add more here if necessary of course.

Comment: Any reason why your controller does not return a ResponseEntity?

Comment: No special reason, JHipster generated it that way for the getAll() of all entities. All other Endpoints (getByID, create, update,...) return a ResponseEntity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test initialization is wrong: `budget` is not attached to any user, that's why the repository method returns an empty list.

```
    User user = userRepository.findOneByLogin("user").get();
    budget.setUser(user);
    budgetRepository.saveAndFlush(budget);
```

Using a `@Query` with `principal` makes it difficult to debug, I prefer a more explicit approach where the login is provided by the resource controller:

```
@GetMapping("/budgets")
public ResponseEntity<List<Budget>> getMyBudgets() {
    List<Budget> budgets = budgetRepository.findByUserLogin(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin());
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(budgets);
}
```

and then the repository no longer needs a `@Query`:

```
public interface BudgetRepository extends JpaRepository<Budget,Long> {

    List<Budget> findAll();

    List<Budget> findByUserLogin(String login);
}
```

As a bonus, you can use same method for an administrator that would want to find the budgets of any user.

Comment: Thank you very much, that totally makes sense, and fixes the issue!